# NRPE: Unable to read output CentOS6

Tags: linux, nagios, nrpe, centreon

I am monitoring a CentOS 6 machine with NTP service installed.
The monitoring server is a CentOS 5 machine with Nagios and Centreon.
I'm using NRPE for monitoring remote hosts, and I get the following error in two of four services that I configured:

```
NRPE: Unable to read output
```

I did `check_nrpe -H (publicserverip)` and everything seems to be OK. Also, I have configured the commands in `nrpe.cfg`

Comment: Can you give an example output of what check_nrpe returns? Nagios is very picky with outputs.

Comment: Service Status  UNKNOWN
Status information  
NRPE: Unable to read output
_______________________________________________________________


That's all, thanks

Comment: What happens when you do the check manually from the command-line on the client machine?

Comment: -bash: /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_mem: Permiso denegado (permission denied)

If I make ls -la, the permission values for check_mem are: -rw-r--r--. 1 root root

I suppose is a permissions issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a permissions issue.

Issue this command and you should be fine: `chmod +x /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_mem`.

In the future, ensure that all nagios plugins are executable.

Comment: Yeah, you were righ, all function properly after aplied chmod 755. Thanks a lot!